# Tkinter: How to dynamically insert items to another listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

Newbie here. I am struggling with Tkinter a bit. I have much more complex program but I created this little script to show you what I'm trying to achieve. I have two listboxes, first one contains some items. When I select one item from first listbox, I want certain thing to be inserted into second listbox.
I know that this has to be done via some loop or sth because if you run this script, second listbox has item `4480104160onselect` instead of index integer of item in first listbox.

I am having problems to look this up in documentation so if you point me to specific part of it or some tutorial, that will work as well. Thank you very much.

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

parentlist = ['one','two','three']
l1 = Listbox()
for item in parentlist:
    l1.insert(END, item)

l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

def onselect(event):
    w = event.widget
    index = w.curselection()[0]
    print "You selected: %d" % int(index)
    return int(index)

l1select = l1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',onselect)

l2 = Listbox()
l2.insert(END, l1select )

l2.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good tutorials. I usually refer to ones here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm or here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm, I prefer the first link because its more verbose.

[EDIT: Just changing the return line to not return but inserting into listbox l2 works.]
[EDIT 2: Passing arguments to onselect]

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

parentlist = ['one','two','three']
l1 = Listbox()
for item in parentlist:
    l1.insert(END, item)

l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
l2 = Listbox()

l2.grid(row=0, column=1)

def onselect(event, test):
    w = event.widget
    index = w.curselection()[0]
    print "You selected: {0} and test variable is {1}".format(index, test) 
    l2.insert(END, index ) # Instead of returning it, why not just insert it here?

l1select = l1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',lambda event: onselect(event, 'Test'))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OK I'm gonna check the links out. Actually I already did the effbot link and it's not making much sense to me.
Anyway, in my original program, I need to work with files. Is there any way to pass more than one argument to `onselect` function? For example a list.

Comment: Using classes will help you have access to class variables, or you can do this: l1select = l1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',lambda event: onselect(event, 'Test'))