# Assigning variable to use for database query in python / tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been too busy to do any coding learning or practice in the past while however with the pandemic I now have a little time to get back to coding.

So... I am using Python 3.7 and tkinter and my intent is to insert data from the DB (sqlite3) into a Listbox widget, all of that part works fine. It is loading a category list of code names. Once the data is inserted into the widget I am trying to have it where a user can then click on 1 of the category names and it will then query the DB for all rows containing that match for that category name and insert the data into another widget. Once again it would allow the user to then click a selection from that widget, which in turn queries the DB again to insert the data into a third widget to display the code snippet.

As an example to better follow what I am working on.
The program runs and displays 3 widgets (1 Listbox which contains the category list already loaded, 1 Listbox which will contain the code list to be inserted after the initial click of a word in the first Listbox, 1 Text widget which will have the data inserted once a selection is made from Listbox #2)

A user will program runs and will already have the Category widget populated with the list of available choices.
The user would then click one of the categories and it would then query the DB to insert all data under that to the code list widget.
Now a user will click on the code name in that widget and it will query the DB and insert the data for the code name selected.

I believe that when the initial Category list is loaded and displayed in the first Listbox each of the items would need to be a variable for the button click to then use the variable assigned to do the query for the code names. I am not sure who to go about this.

What I am having trouble with is finding the correct way to assign a variable for the query for each category and then each code name once populated.

My Listbox for Categories:

```
categoryFrame = LabelFrame(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1, bg = '#FFFFDF', width = 278, height = 202, bd = 2)
categoryFrame.place(x=978,y=55)
category_label = Label(root, text='Categories', font = ('arial', 8, 'bold'), bd = 2,width = '20', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg='#284287', relief = RAISED)
category_label.place(x=978,y=33)
category = Listbox(root, font = ('arial', 8, 'bold'), bg='#FFFFDF', fg='#000000', width=45, height=13, highlightthickness=0, relief=SUNKEN)
category.place(x=980,y=57)
category.bind('<Button-1>', getList)
```

My second Listbox for Item List:

```
snippetFrame = LabelFrame(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1, bg = '#FFFFDF', width = 278, height = 203, bd = 2)
snippetFrame.place(x=978,y=291)
snippet_list_label = Label(root, text='Snippet List', font = ('arial', 8, 'bold'), bd = 2, width = '20', fg = '#FFFFFF', bg='#284287', relief = RAISED)
snippet_list_label.place(x=978,y=269)
snippet_list = Listbox(root, font = ('arial', 8, 'bold'), bg='#FFFFDF', fg='#000000', bd=0, width=45, height=13, highlightthickness=0, relief=SUNKEN)
snippet_list.place(x=980,y=296)
snippet_list.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', getCode)
```

The DB query can only be written once I know how to assign a variable to the items in the category list but I believe it should be something like this.

```
selection = category.get() #this is not the correct "get"
c.execute('SELECT Snippet_Name FROM Code Type WHERE Code_Type = :selection ORDER BY Snippet_Name DESC', {'selection': selection})
results = c.fetchall()
for result, in results:
    snippet_list.insert(0,result)
```

Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want something like this [tkinter-how-to-dynamically-insert-items-to-another-listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560613)?

Comment: This is in essence what I am attempting to get correctly but using a DB query with sqlite3. I have the first Listbox-1 populated, as in the example from the link you provided. When an category is clicked it should query the DB to populate Listbox-2 with the "snippet names" for all items in the "code type" column that was clicked on in Listbox-1.

Comment: Read this answer [python-dependant-combobox-based-on-sqlite-db-values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60841393/7414759), it's `Combobox` but the steps are the same.

Comment: @stovfl, I have tried to adapt the coding from the link you provided but I have been unsuccessful.  I guess I am not following it correctly.  I have the DB query working correctly to populate Listbox-1 (Category) but I have not figured out how to be able to click 1 of the items in that category list to query the DB and get the data for all items in the name list and populate it to the Listbox - 2 (Name List).  I'm still stumped I guess.

Comment: Sounds you don't have a proper callback. Read [unexpected-behavior-with-tkinter-and-two-listboxes-bound-to-listboxselect-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991760)

Comment: @stovfl, I appreciate the links provided.  After reading all of them and some trials I now have the DB query working properly.  Thank you again. :)

Comment: Upvote some or all answers at the given links if there are helpful.